# Static keyword in Cuda

Tags: cuda

Just wondering why is it that for C/C++ one would explicitly qualify a static storage variable with the keyword "static", and not enforce the same on Cuda. As far as I understand, a static variable on, e.g device, in Cuda is simply: `int v = 0.0f;`

For those of you who know more, correct me if I am wrong. Thanks,

Amine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might depend on how exactly you are using `static` and what your expectations are.  As far as I know, CUDA claims to be a [fairly complete standards-compliant C++ implementation with stated restrictions and limitations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support), and from what I can tell this simple usage of `static` behaves as I would expect, and it is certainly not the case that a static variable is implied without the `static` keyword:

```
$ cat t80.cu
#include <cstdio>

__device__ void test(){
#ifdef USE_STATIC
       static int i = 0;
#else
       int i = 0;
#endif
       printf("i = %d\n", i);
       i++;}

__global__ void k(){
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) test();
}

int main(){
       k<<<1,1>>>();
       cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t80 t80.cu
$ ./t80
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
$ nvcc -o t80 t80.cu -DUSE_STATIC
$ ./t80
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
$
```

I don't see how you could support this claim:

> a static variable on, e.g device, in Cuda is simply: int v = 0.0f;

based on the above test case.

Comment: Apologies for the implied claim, I completely misunderstood the context of the explanation I was reading. It was to do with static initialization rather than a static variable. My mistake. thanks